# Powershell [ComponentModel.Win32Exception] casting inconsistencies

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get my head around windows errors, especially the relationship between Win32 errors and HRESULT errors.

So, as an example I know **3010** is

> "The requested operation is successful. Changes will not be effective
>   until the system is rebooted"

And I can get that by casting to ComponentModel.Win32Exception thus: `[ComponentModel.Win32Exception]3010`.

Also, I know that **3010** is expressed in hex as **0x00000BC2** or **0x0BC2**, and I can cast both of those as well. But it can also be expressed as **0x80070bc2**, and this will cast properly. And it can even be expressed as **0xFFFFFFFF80070BC2**. Here, as a 64 bit hex value it won't cast. But, **0xFFFFFFFF80070BC2** is **-2147021886** in decimal, and that will cast. And it's a return value that can be expected, as documented [here](http://woshub.com/all-windows-update-error-codes/).

Similarly **0** decimal can be expressed in hex as 0x0000 and 0x00000000 and those cast fine and return

> "The operation completed successfully"

But **0xFFFFFFFF00000000** and the decimal equivalent **-4294967296** won't cast, they both return the decimal value. But I have gotten that decimal value returned from an installer, and the website referenced above also includes that decimal value.

So, at times when running installers from various vendors I have seen 0, -4294967296, 3010 & -2147021886 returned, and in three of the four situations I can cast to get a meaningful message for the user, and in one I can't.

So, to sum up, why are these BAD values bad, and why are they inconsistent, and what is the best way to deal with values like **-4294967296** or **-2147945410**, the latter of which may never show up, but the former of which I have seen.

```
[ComponentModel.Win32Exception]3010 # Good
[ComponentModel.Win32Exception]0x0BC2 # Good

[ComponentModel.Win32Exception]-2147021886 # Good
[ComponentModel.Win32Exception]0x00000BC2 # Good
[ComponentModel.Win32Exception]0x0000000000000BC2 # Good

[ComponentModel.Win32Exception]-2147945410 # BAD
[ComponentModel.Win32Exception]0x80070BC2 # Good
[ComponentModel.Win32Exception]0x0000000080070BC2 # Good

[ComponentModel.Win32Exception]0 # Good
[ComponentModel.Win32Exception]0x0000 # Good

[ComponentModel.Win32Exception]0x00000000 # Good
[ComponentModel.Win32Exception]0x0000000000000000 # Good

[ComponentModel.Win32Exception]0xFFFFFFFF00000000 # BAD
[ComponentModel.Win32Exception]-4294967296 # BAD
```

EDIT: So, I have dug around a bit, and I THINK this might work.

```
foreach ($errCode in @(0, 3010, -2147021886, -4294967296)) {
    [int]$intCode = $errCode -band 0xFFFF
    [ComponentModel.Win32Exception]$intCode
}
```

For the four values in question it does, but I'll need to test with a bunch of others too. Still just don't understand why Microsoft Autodesk and the rest will return values that can't be used easily. Why not just use nothing but the damn Win32 codes and be done with it? And why is 0x80070BC2 treated the same as 0x00000BC2 and both work, but their decimal equivalents are treated differently and only one works?

Comment: `-2147021886` will fit in an `Int32`, `-2147945410` will not. There is no constructor for `Win32Exception` that takes an `Int64`, so PowerShell decides to use the one taking a `String` instead, which of course results in just the same value echoed back. A value like `-4294967296` is not an HRESULT and cannot be interpreted as such; taking the lower 32 bits just gives `0`, which is probably not meaningful. 32-bit errors that have been sign-extended to 64-bits can be properly interpreted, but something like `-4294967296` will always need special treatment.

Comment: Ah, Jeroen, I found that solution in parallel with your response. ;) It feels like this may be the answer, but I feel like I still don't understand WHY it's even needed.

Comment: It depends on how you're actually obtaining this "return value". `-4294967296` cannot be the exit status of a process, as those too are limited to 32 bits. The installer may internally use 64-bit numbers and print these to a log file or standard output, but those are not actual exit codes, HRESULTs or error codes as obtained by `GetLastError()`. (In a sense it doesn't matter that `Win32Exception` can't handle them, because it will never print meaningful messages for them.)

Comment: @Jeroen, at least in the case of `-4294967296` it is returned by some Autodesk installers. Now Autodesk's installer creation team is, um, not competent, so it wouldn't surprise me if that are soiling the bed as it where.

Comment: The reason `0x80070bc2` is treated the same as `0x0bc2` is fairly simple: the former is just the same Win32 error code encoded as an HRESULT (top bit indicates failure, facility 7 = Win32, 3010 = error code). These values mean the same thing despite not having the same numerical value (whereas `0xffffffff80070bc2` is just the a 64-bit sign-extended value of `0x80070bc2`, and is thus actually the same numerical value expressed in a different number of bits). `0xffffffff00000000` isn't much of anything aside from a generic "something went wrong" that won't fit in 32 bits.

Comment: Hmm, now I am even more confused. `0xffffffff00000000`] is a generic FAILURE? Even though extracting the meaningful Win32 positive integer out of the last 4 hex digits and casting to `Win32Exception` produces the success message that also seems to have been what actually happened with the install?

Comment: If it is supposed to be a success code it's even more confusing, because the value as a whole is negative, which would generally indicate a problem (because of the convention that HRESULTs set the top bit to 1 on failure, which produces negative values when the number is interpreted in two's complement). If you find the installation was actually successful, then apparently discarding the top 32 bits entirely is always the way to go. I don't know the way this installer rolls.

Comment: Well, in general 0 is Error_Success, which makes no sense, but it's common. And -4294967296 is documented at http://woshub.com/all-windows-update-error-codes/ as x00000000 -4294967296 Success, which Looks like exactly that, discard top 32 bits and what's left is a success, using an error code. Of course Microsoft could have saved the confusion by just calling them Exit codes, where the vase majority of conditions expressed are errors, some are informational (Success, reboot required) and one, 0, is just a simple success with no caveats.

Comment: Window uses different error code types, HRESULT, NTSTATUS and other (Win32) errors. See e.g. https://jpassing.com/2007/08/20/error-codes-win32-vs-hresult-vs-ntstatus/